# Add firewall rule while Windows Firewall service is disabled

Tags: windows, firewall, windows-firewall, netsh

While Windows Firewall service is disabled trying to apply this ↓ command

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="My App (HTTP-In)" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=1234 remoteip=localsubnet program=SYSTEM
```

causes this error:

```
An error occurred while attempting to contact the  Windows Firewall service. Make sure that the service is running and try your request again.
```

I know that you can add rules directly through Registry Editor by adding values to this ↓ key, but I would like to omit this way.

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules
```

The question is: Is there another way to add firewall rules while Windows Firewall service is disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, because the Firewall service isn't running.  Enable it, add the rules with `netsh`, and then disable it when done.  Or add via the registry as you have suggested.

Either way should be pretty painless to repeat once you've scripted it once.

Comment: Agreed.  If OP needs to test it with minimal disruption to a service, I would say test the script on another PC first.

Comment: As stated in [TechNet Magazine 2007](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.06.vistafirewall.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), it's better to only use the service instead of registry for editing firewall rules. So I will stick to Start/Edit/Stop method.